# How to define dictionary whose values are showing of what type should be a property, which name is used as key?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am working on application, which should verify a JSON.
The properties are of different types (numeric, string, date), that is why I have not only to verify the presence of the properties, but also whether their value is of the required type.

That is why I would like to define dictionary, which key will be the name of the property and the value will be the type, that this property should be of (with the operator `isinstance` or in some other way). But I do not know how to implement this in Python. Something like this:

```
map_of_property_to_classes: Dict[str, any]
class_name = map_of_property_to_classes["property_name"]
print(isinstance("property_name", class_name))
```

Can somebody give a hint?

Comment: This could match your needs: https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/

Comment: JSON only has a relatively small number of [possible values](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), so check their type doesn't make much sense. Are you using something to transform the JSON into the Python data-types you mention in your question, like `date`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like the below?

```
from typing import Dict


def validate(data: Dict, meta_data: Dict) -> None:
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, meta_data[k]):
            print('OK')
        else:
            print(f'{v} must be of type {meta_data[k]}')


_data = {'x': 12, 'name': 12}
_meta_data = {'x': int, 'name': str}
validate(_data,_meta_data)
```

output

```
OK
12 must be of type <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I wonder if something like [numbers.Real](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Real) would be a better type for validating JSON numbers.

Comment: @Balderman - Yes and no. Actually what i did not mention, is that i  would like to pass this meta_data as argument of a method - that is why i actually wanted to understand how exactly to define this?

Comment: Code was modified - have a look.

Comment: I am glad I managed to help. You may accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer your question but I have written a script which read a JSON file and return a dict.

Here's the JSON file:

```
"Config":{
    "programming_languages" : {"_type" : "dict", "value" :  {
      "py"    : "python",
      "js"    : "javascript",
      "txt"   : "plain",
      "md"      : "markdown",
      "cs"      : "csharp"
    }},
    "noEditTypes": {"_type" : "set", "value" : ["pdf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png"]}
}
```

And here's the python Code:

```
@staticmethod
def configParser():
    with open("data/data.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f).get("Config")
        outData = {}
        for i in data:
            valTypeName = data[i].get("_type")
            if valTypeName == "set":
                valType = set
            elif valTypeName == "str":
                valType = str
            elif valTypeName == "int":
                valType = int
            elif valTypeName == "list":
                valType = list
            elif valTypeName == "dict":
                valType = dict
            else:
                raise Exception("Unknown Type: {}".format(valTypeName))
            valvalue = data[i].get("value")

            outData[i] = valType(valvalue)
    return outData
```

I think if you modify this code a bit it would also work for your intended use.